# Is there a standalone C++ source preprocessor?

Tags: c++, windows, c-preprocessor

Is there a standalone C++ preprocessor? I don't need the compiler/linker, and I'm not able to install a full kit.

I'd like to be able to obtain preprocessed version of some headers, using some defines and include paths I provide.

EDIT: I can't rely on anything being available. No **cl**, no **gcc**, nothing. The least I would need done is something that processes macros ( specifically #ifdef and #if ).

EDIT: I'm using this on a Windows XP computer.

Comment: Standalones? Not that I know of. gcc, however, INCLUDES a preprocessor(see gcc -E)

Comment: What OS are you trying to get a preprocessor for? UNIX systems generally have cpp installed. For Windows, cl.exe can do preprocessing only if you give it the right command-line options.

Answer (score 10):

cpp is what you're looking for. I am not sure if it can be gotten outside of gcc distribution, though

```
CPP(1)                                                                 GNU                                                                 CPP(1)

NAME
       cpp - The C Preprocessor

SYNOPSIS
       cpp [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro]
           [-Idir...] [-Wwarn...]
           [-M|-MM] [-MG] [-MF filename]
           [-MP] [-MQ target...]
           [-MT target...]
           [-P] [-fno-working-directory]
           [-x language] [-std=standard]
           infile outfile

Only the most useful options are listed here; see below for the remainder.

DESCRIPTION
       The C preprocessor, often known as cpp, is a macro processor that is used automatically by the C compiler to transform your program before
       compilation.  It is called a macro processor because it allows you to define macros, which are brief abbreviations for longer constructs.
```

Answer (score 6):

Many compilers have a command-line option that will do what you want.

For example, GCC's is `-E`, and MSVC's is `/P`.

Comment: All gcc does in invoke the correct application to do the work. gcc/g++ both use cpp on linux/unix environments.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at [Boost Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/wave/doc/introduction.html). It's a preprocessor built as a library instead of an application, but putting a wrapper around it to turn it into a standalone program should be fairly trivial (most of what you'd do is connect things up so it knows what file(s) to read from and write to).

Comment: I'm fairly certain I've seen already seen such a wrapper, although I'm not entirely certain if that was part of the package.

Comment: The application is called "Wave driver". It works.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to have a look at [GPP, Generic Pre Processor](http://math.mit.edu/~auroux/software/gpp.html).  It's customizable but it looks like it comes with some predefined setting which will do C/C++ preprocessing.

Edit: Looks like -C is the setting to use

> -C
>   cpp compatibility mode. This is the mode where gpp's behavior is the closest to that of >cpp. Unlike in the default mode, meta-macro expansion occurs only at the beginning of >lines, and C comments and strings are understood.

Comment: Does it work on windows?

Comment: The version at http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP works on Windows and Visual Studio with a few modifications. Eg, the latest version (circa 2004) of gpp.c on that site expects fnmatch to be defined. On Windows, if you're using VS instead of MiniGW, you can use the following: #define fnmatch(pattern, string, flags) (!(PathMatchSpec(string, pattern) == TRUE)). There are a few other trivial changes if you don't generate config.h

Answer (score 6):

http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/

mpp portable c preprocessor:

> > mcpp project was selected as one of the year 2002 "Exploratory Software Projects" at Information-Technology Promotion Agency, Japan (IPA), and selected again for the year 2003 projects. For the achievements of the project, the author was evaluated as one of the highest class programmers<<

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could *try* to build your own app using the standalone library, [cpplib](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/), but while they supply it, they don't recommend using it that way as it "has not yet reached a point of reasonable stability." I don't know how long that has been true.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the C++ compiler provides you with an option to see the preprocessed source.

With GCC, as was commented, you use:

```
g++ -E ...other options... files
```

On some systems, especially Unix systems, there may be a separate 'cpp' program.  On MacOS X it installed as /usr/bin/cpp and is part of the GCC (GNU Compiler Collection).

Sometimes, it is installed in more out of the way places - on Solaris 10, it is /usr/lib/cpp, for example.