# The Preprocessor program linked in g++ similar to the cpp program in gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I was going through this book - An Introduction to GCC by Brian Gough where he talks about the GNU C preprocessor `cpp` and how its provided as a separate package even though its integrated into the compiler.

I was wondering if there is a similar command that is provided as a part of the `g++` package that can show me all the expanded macros before compiling the source code.

I know there is the `-E` option supported by both `gcc` and `g++` which stops after the preprocessing stage but was curious if there is something similar to `cpp` in `g++`

Comment: You mean as with `ld`, that it can be called as aseparate program?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes. As a separate program

Comment: A separate program that simply calls `gcc -E` is trivial to write, and seems to do exactly what you ask for, so can you explain in what way calling `gcc -E` directly would not be good enough for whatever you want to use it for?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is one, but did you check the folder where gcc was installed?

Comment: btw `g++ -E` works without any problem

Comment: @hvd I can call g++ with -E. But I wanted to know if there is a separate program like cpp provided with the g++ package

Comment: Yes - it's called `cpp`.  g++ package include gcc and all other tool depencencies

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645538/is-there-a-standalone-c-source-preprocessor

Comment: @bolov: That sounds like a dupe, doesn't it?

Comment: @selbie thanks. But it wouldn't work on my CPP program. Says it can't find the file iostream. So thought there must be a different program provided by g++

Comment: @bolov thanks. Will look in to it

Comment: @rgk There's `cpp -xc++`, which is pretty much the same thing as `g++ -E`.

Comment: @bolov Yeah. This question is a duplicate of the link that you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the preprocessing level, there isn't much difference between the two languages. It's just a matter of telling the preprocessor how to resolve includes (i.e. telling it the correct include paths) and defining certain macros (like `__cplusplus`). So the same program you use to expand preprocessor code in C should do the job for C++.

Comment: Lexing is different too between C and C++, particularly with the hexadecimal floating-point literals in C99, and the raw string literals and string literal suffixes in C++11. Given `#define X(x) "abc"x`, older code often expected `X("def")` to expand to two string literal tokens which would be concatenated, as it would in C, but C++ no longer works like that.

Comment: The cpp command did not work with my c++ program. It quit with the error couldn't find the file iostream.h. That made me think there is a separate program. Will look in to how to run it with CPP code